# ¿Cómo manejar un mensaje Segmentation fault (core dumped) con pip?

Tags: python, pip, out-of-memory-error

Recientemente, cuando descargo módulos de Python con ... Tengo esto como final de mensaje

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

No sé si me duele como puedes ver en el ejemplo de abajo pero me preocupa

Por ejemplo, intentando instalar rasa_nlu :

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa_tutorial/moodbot/rasa_nlu$ python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting gevent==1.2.2 (from -r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 1))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/fe/1d681dc31f61cb95fcc55e9c3baf7117e52db78270aa1bf169262f86707e/gevent-1.2.2-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting klein==17.10.0 (from -r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 2))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/6b/adc97a7bb3fb781fdd9e49177ad873c1479f87b9745271cbeda81cbb9cc8/klein-17.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting hyperlink==17.3.1 (from -r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 3))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d9/1a/baab6a42ba1591efe73b30d86a25953d9235f5f22da5d18e879a79d86151/hyperlink-17.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting boto3==1.5.20 (from -r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 4))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/66/eab831d906a2b0c93939691e875d0a9b583928aa22b2ea950326795ae7ec/boto3-1.5.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting typing==3.6.2 (from -r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 5))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1c/15/aeaae0c01afa895ad774cfd408eca17818fd753817d433f55385d8e36364/typing-3.6.2-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting future==0.16.0 (from -r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 6))
Collecting six==1.11.0 (from -r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 7))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/4b/141a581104b1f6397bfa78ac9d43d8ad29a7ca43ea90a2d863fe3056e86a/six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jsonschema==2.6.0 (from -r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 8))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/77/de/47e35a97b2b05c2fadbec67d44cfcdcd09b8086951b331d82de90d2912da/jsonschema-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting matplotlib==2.1.0 (from -r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 9))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/b2/41ae0d5922a8018c1f506ef9b9363fca60326c8b24241b13ecaf80fede47/matplotlib-2.1.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting requests==2.18.4 (from -r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 10))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/49/df/50aa1999ab9bde74656c2919d9c0c085fd2b3775fd3eca826012bef76d8c/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting tqdm==4.19.5 (from -r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 11))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/3c/341b4fa23cb3abc335207dba057c790f3bb329f6757e1fcd5d347bcf8308/tqdm-4.19.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting numpy==1.14.0 (from -r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 12))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0d/8a/e0223a40f980e0442a2045dcf79e4a8a90339593525599a0add318da2428/numpy-1.14.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting simplejson==3.13.2 (from -r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 13))
Collecting cloudpickle==0.5.2 (from -r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 14))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/aa/18/514b557c4d8d4ada1f0454ad06c845454ad438fd5c5e0039ba51d6b032fe/cloudpickle-0.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting msgpack-python==0.5.4 (from -r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 15))
Collecting packaging==17.1 (from -r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 16))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ad/c2/b500ea05d5f9f361a562f089fc91f77ed3b4783e13a08a3daf82069b1224/packaging-17.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyyaml==3.12 (from -r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 17))
Collecting coloredlogs==9.0 (from -r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 18))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c6/fe/a602b8b2cacfd99a6d92d0064464ad13baf96c0da7cdac15b6b612834c64/coloredlogs-9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting greenlet>=0.4.10 (from gevent==1.2.2->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 1))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/e5/191ba8664e4c388646b91c9891e15381cb1b515e9c9059d1e6485d5ebbe3/greenlet-0.4.13-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting Twisted>=15.5 (from klein==17.10.0->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 2))
Collecting werkzeug (from klein==17.10.0->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 2))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/c4/12e3e56473e52375aa29c4764e70d1b8f3efa6682bef8d0aae04fe335243/Werkzeug-0.14.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting incremental (from klein==17.10.0->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 2))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/1d/c98a587dc06e107115cf4a58b49de20b19222c83d75335a192052af4c4b7/incremental-17.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.10 (from boto3==1.5.20->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 4))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d7/14/2a0004d487464d120c9fb85313a75cd3d71a7506955be458eebfe19a6b1d/s3transfer-0.1.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 (from boto3==1.5.20->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 4))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/31/05c8d001f7f87f0f07289a5fc0fc3832e9a57f2dbd4d3b0fee70e0d51365/jmespath-0.9.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting botocore<1.9.0,>=1.8.34 (from boto3==1.5.20->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 4))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5a/9f/c74178afb86983446a4aea1f308272f6e92a96dd7b6efd086eb50241b10c/botocore-1.8.50-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting functools32; python_version == "2.7" (from jsonschema==2.6.0->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 8))
Collecting pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 (from matplotlib==2.1.0->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 9))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/8a/718fd7d3458f9fab8e67186b00abdd345b639976bc7fb3ae722e1b026a50/pyparsing-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting backports.functools-lru-cache (from matplotlib==2.1.0->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 9))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/03/8e/2424c0e65c4a066e28f539364deee49b6451f8fcd4f718fefa50cc3dcf48/backports.functools_lru_cache-1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.0 (from matplotlib==2.1.0->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 9))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/f5/af2b09c957ace60dcfac112b669c45c8c97e32f94aa8b56da4c6d1682825/python_dateutil-2.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting subprocess32 (from matplotlib==2.1.0->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 9))
Collecting pytz (from matplotlib==2.1.0->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 9))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dc/83/15f7833b70d3e067ca91467ca245bae0f6fe56ddc7451aa0dc5606b120f2/pytz-2018.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cycler>=0.10 (from matplotlib==2.1.0->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 9))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f7/d2/e07d3ebb2bd7af696440ce7e754c59dd546ffe1bbe732c8ab68b9c834e61/cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests==2.18.4->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 10))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/e6/92ad559b7192d846975fc916b65f667c7b8c3a32bea7372340bfe9a15fa5/certifi-2018.4.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests==2.18.4->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 10))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<2.7,>=2.5 (from requests==2.18.4->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 10))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/27/cc/6dd9a3869f15c2edfab863b992838277279ce92663d334df9ecf5106f5c6/idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 (from requests==2.18.4->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 10))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/cb/6965947c13a94236f6d4b8223e21beb4d576dc72e8130bd7880f600839b8/urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting humanfriendly>=4.7 (from coloredlogs==9.0->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 18))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4a/4f/16881101fb87370fd62bdc1b7b895c505c6525a9b07e10571bf41899937b/humanfriendly-4.12.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting constantly>=15.1 (from Twisted>=15.5->klein==17.10.0->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 2))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/65/48c1909d0c0aeae6c10213340ce682db01b48ea900a7d9fce7a7910ff318/constantly-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting zope.interface>=4.4.2 (from Twisted>=15.5->klein==17.10.0->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 2))
Collecting Automat>=0.3.0 (from Twisted>=15.5->klein==17.10.0->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 2))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/17/6a/1baf488c2015ecafda48c03ca984cf0c48c254622668eb1732dbe2eae118/Automat-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting futures<4.0.0,>=2.2.0; python_version == "2.6" or python_version == "2.7" (from s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.10->boto3==1.5.20->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 4))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2d/99/b2c4e9d5a30f6471e410a146232b4118e697fa3ffc06d6a65efde84debd0/futures-3.2.0-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting docutils>=0.10 (from botocore<1.9.0,>=1.8.34->boto3==1.5.20->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 4))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/50/09/c53398e0005b11f7ffb27b7aa720c617aba53be4fb4f4f3f06b9b5c60f28/docutils-0.14-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting monotonic; python_version == "2.6" or python_version == "2.7" or python_version == "3.0" or python_version == "3.1" or python_version == "3.2" (from humanfriendly>=4.7->coloredlogs==9.0->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 18))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/aa/063eca6a416f397bd99552c534c6d11d57f58f2e94c14780f3bbf818c4cf/monotonic-1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools (from zope.interface>=4.4.2->Twisted>=15.5->klein==17.10.0->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 2))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/10/79282747f9169f21c053c562a0baa21815a8c7879be97abd930dbcf862e8/setuptools-39.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting attrs (from Automat>=0.3.0->Twisted>=15.5->klein==17.10.0->-r alt_requirements/requirements_bare.txt (line 2))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/59/cedf87e91ed541be7957c501a92102f9cc6363c623a7666d69d51c78ac5b/attrs-18.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: greenlet, gevent, hyperlink, constantly, incremental, setuptools, zope.interface, attrs, six, Automat, Twisted, werkzeug, klein, futures, jmespath, docutils, python-dateutil, botocore, s3transfer, boto3, typing, future, functools32, jsonschema, pyparsing, backports.functools-lru-cache, subprocess32, pytz, cycler, numpy, matplotlib, certifi, chardet, idna, urllib3, requests, tqdm, simplejson, cloudpickle, msgpack-python, packaging, pyyaml, monotonic, humanfriendly, coloredlogs
Successfully installed Automat-0.6.0 Twisted-18.4.0 attrs-18.1.0 backports.functools-lru-cache-1.5 boto3-1.5.20 botocore-1.10.19 certifi-2018.4.16 chardet-3.0.4 cloudpickle-0.5.2 coloredlogs-9.0 constantly-15.1.0 cycler-0.10.0 docutils-0.14 functools32-3.2.3.post2 future-0.16.0 futures-3.2.0 gevent-1.3.0 greenlet-0.4.13 humanfriendly-4.12.1 hyperlink-17.3.1 idna-2.6 incremental-17.5.0 jmespath-0.9.3 jsonschema-2.6.0 klein-17.10.0 matplotlib-2.2.2 monotonic-1.5 msgpack-python-0.5.6 numpy-1.11.0 packaging-17.1 pyparsing-2.0.3 python-dateutil-2.4.2 pytz-2014.10 pyyaml-3.12 requests-2.18.4 s3transfer-0.1.13 setuptools-20.7.0 simplejson-3.14.0 six-1.10.0 subprocess32-3.2.7 tqdm-4.23.3 typing-3.6.4 urllib3-1.22 werkzeug-0.14.1 zope.interface-4.5.0
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: `"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"` es la cadena que linux imprime cuando un programa existe con una señal  `SIGSEGV` y tiene habilitada la creación del núcleo. Esto significa que algún programa se ha bloqueado. Si realmente está obteniendo este error esto significa que el intérprete de `Python` se ha bloqueado.

Comment: Otra cosa es posible que esté trabajando con una gran cantidad de datos y su memoria RAM está llena

Comment: @J.Rodríguez Hmm, compriendo. Sin embargo, no estoy seguro que me pone problemas por lo momento. ¿Que piensa usted segun la salida que mostré ?

Comment: Tal como se muestra el código que ha puesta es difícil de interpretar.

Comment: @J.Rodríguez Si pero parece que el error es realmente al final

Comment: Primero que nada por qué no intenta hacer lo que le muestra el mensaje?  actualizar de la `pip version 8.1.1` a `10.0.1` con el comando `pip install --upgrade pip` intente esto primero y si vuelve a tener el error, comenteme.

Comment: @J.Rodríguez el problema es que pip no actualice más cuando uso este comando como puede ver en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/163604/pip-ya-no-se-actualiza)

Comment: @J.Rodríguez Disculpe, [aqui](https://www.onlinegdb.com/SJtvStNRz) esta el enlace

Answer (score 1):

Aquí tiene la documentación para instalar `Rasa NLU`:

> - https://nlu.rasa.com/installation.html
> - https://spacy.io/usage/models#download
> - https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/blob/master/docs/installation.rst

Para actualizar `pip` como cualquier otro paquete así:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

En Windows, el [comando recomendado](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip) es:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

> En Windows puede tener un problema de permisos al intentar actualizar pip. En su lugar, utilicé `easy_install` para actualizar: `easy_install pip`

También puede ocurrir que su versión de `pip` este rota, por lo que la actualización por sí sola no funcionaría.

Puede usar:

```
(inside virtualenv):easy_install -U pip
```

---

Según el [comentario que me mencionado aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/163566/c%c3%b3mo-manejar-un-mensaje-segmentation-fault-core-dumped-con-pip?noredirect=1#comment309890_163566), noto que le muestra este error:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip'

Esto puede solucionarlo usando [Pipenv & Virtual Environments(virtualenv)](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/), podría recrear accidentalmente virtualenv con `Python2` olvidándose de poner la ruta al intérprete de `Python3` para que cuando ejecute `pip3` se refiera al sistema `Python3`.

Asegúrese de utilizar el `Python` correcto en su entorno virtual y también asegúrese de crear `virtualenv` con `pip` (sí, es la opción predeterminada, pero no se cómo crea su entorno virtual).

Puede intentar esto:

**Instalar**

- Asegúrate de haber instalado virtualenv [aquí](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)
- Esto es opcional, pero también puede utilizar `virtualenvwrapper` para usar el comando `workon` [aquí](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) , de lo contrario puedes simplemente hacer `source bin/activate` desde el `virtualenv`

**Crear Virtualenv**

Muchas personas recomiendan **[`sudo`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47071257/8933039)** pero hacer esto puede que instale sus bibliotecas de proyectos en todo el sistema (lo que se verá afectado cuando tenga más de un proyecto). En su lugar, use `virtualenvs` como este ejemplo:

```
$mkvirtualenv myenv --python=python3.5
$workon myenv
$pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Esto te prepara configurando tu virtualenv `'myenv'` y especificando qué `python` estás usando. A continuación, activa el entorno y puede instalar su archivo de requisitos.

> También aquí le dejo este enlace de SO: [¿Por qué PIP no actualiza el paquete?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27306908/8933039) por si le sirve.

---

Con respecto al mensaje: **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

Encontré esto al respecto en SO:

> - [Error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13654489/8933039)
> - [What causes a Python segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10035541/8933039)

De mi parte es todo en cuanto puedo ayudarle, espero le sirva, saludos.!