# Pip ya no se actualiza ¿Falta el modulo _internal?

Tags: python, pip

Cuando instalo `modules` con `pip` me dice que debería actualizarlo. Sin embargo, al actualizar no cambia nada:

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa_tutorial/moodbot$ python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 720kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-8.1.1
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa_tutorial/moodbot$ sudo -H pip install --upgrade pip
[sudo] password for mike: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
ImportError: No module named _internal
```

Estas son las versiones de Python que utilizo:

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa_tutorial/moodbot$ python -V
Python 2.7.12
mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa_tutorial/moodbot$ python3 -V
Python 3.5.2
```

Y esto es lo que he intentado:

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa_tutorial/moodbot$ python -m pip3 install --upgrade pip
/usr/bin/python: No module named pip3
mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa_tutorial/moodbot$ python3 -m pip3 install --upgrade pip
/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip3
```

Comment: Qué versión de Python tienes?

Comment: Usas `pip2`, `pip3`... ?

Comment: @JuanSebastiánVargas, Acabo de añadir lo

Comment: @J.Rodríguez, no funciona tampoco, he añadido los resultados

Comment: @Marine1 vea esto: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39129450/8933039 a ver si te sirve

Comment: @J.Rodríguez Lamentablemente, al intentar el enlace tengo (estos errores)[https://onlinegdb.com/SJtvStNRz] que me siguen como la peste

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar esto:

`https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`

Luego esto:

```
python get-pip.py --force-reinstall
```

Para reinstalar pip en la versión más actual

Comment: Y como utilisas el vinculo ? Es imposible utilisarlo en el terminal